# combine SVN checkout, bdist_wheel, pip install?

Tags: python, svn, pip

I have a growing number of private packages, which live in SVN under `/mainrepo/myname/`

I would for users of my packages to be able to check them out of SVN, build a wheel for each project, and run `pip install` on each wheel file.

Now I do this by automating these system calls using a python script:

```
svn checkout <svnurl>
python setup.py bdist_wheel
pip install --no-index --find-links file:////temp/dist/<packagename>
```

Am I just ignorant of some unified set of features in pip that accomplish the same thing?

Comment: Please don't add tags that don't relate to your question. (I've removed the [tag:git] tag, since this question has nothing to do with Git.)

Comment: It could just as easily apply to git actually I just happen to use svn

Comment: That may be, but the solution will likely be slightly different when using Git vs. SVN, so it's probably better to have a separate question for that.